# What can cause java.sql.Statement#executeBatch to return SUCCESS_NO_INFO as one of its values?

Tags: java, sql

In the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) of `java.sql.Statement#executeBatch`, it states that one of the possible values of the elements in the returned `int` array can be:

> A value of SUCCESS_NO_INFO -- indicates that the command was processed successfully but that the number of rows affected is unknown

So it's pretty clear what the value means if you get it. However, on the particular set of queries I am trying to execute as a batch (which only perform updates, nothing fancy), the result array of calling this method contains *only* `SUCCESS_NO_INFO` values. Which inspires me to beg the question: what actually *causes* a successful query execution, but leaves behind no information about the success? I can't find any documentation on this particular topic.

Comment: maybe ddl statements?

Comment: Which jdbc driver are you using?

Comment: ojdbc14, version 10.2.0.4.0, but in the near future will be upgrading to ojdbc5, version 11.2.0.3